# Cannot set property 'key' of undefined angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, modal-dialog, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create modal form. Some fields for this form are standards and some of this fields are custom and come from api request.

```
   {
  "model": {
    "eventTypeId": 1,
    "occuredDate": "2016-08-16T19:58:00.965+0000",
    "categories": []
  },
  "fields": [
    {
      "key": "siteId",
      "type": "input",
      "templateOptions": {
        "label": "Site Id",
        "placeholder": "Site Id"
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "patientId",
      "type": "input",
      "templateOptions": {
        "label": "Patient Id"
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "visitNumber",
      "type": "select",
      "templateOptions": {
        "label": "Visit Number",
        "options": [
          {
            "name": "Screening",
            "value": "Screening"
          },
          {
            "name": " Period 1 Day 0",
            "value": " Period 1 Day 0"
          },
          {
            "name": " Period 1 Day 2",
            "value": " Period 1 Day 2"
          },
          {
            "name": " Period 2 Day 0",
            "value": " Period 2 Day 0"
          },
          {
            "name": " Period 2 Day 2",
            "value": " Period 2 Day 2"
          },
          {
            "name": " Period 3 Day 0",
            "value": " Period 3 Day 0"
          },
          {
            "name": " Period 3 Day 2",
            "value": " Period 3 Day 2"
          },
          {
            "name": " Period 4 Day 0",
            "value": " Period 4 Day 0"
          },
          {
            "name": " Period 4 Day 2",
            "value": " Period 4 Day 2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Unscheduled",
            "value": "Unscheduled Visit"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "sourceSystemRecordId",
      "type": "input",
      "templateOptions": {
        "label": "System Record Id",
        "placeholder": "Source System Record Id"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Without custom fields form works great, I can fill any fields and it will be post, however I try to fill custom fields, I get an error

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'key' of undefined

The template for custom fields looks like:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="(key, value) in vfields">
                <div ng-if="vfields[key].type == 'input'">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fieldId">{{vfields[key].templateOptions.label}}</label>
                        <input type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               id="fieldId"
                               placeholder="{{vfields[key].templateOptions.placeholder}}"
                               ng-model="vmodel.vfields[key].key"
                        >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="vfields[key].type == 'select'">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fieldId">{{vfields[key].templateOptions.label}}</label>
                        <select class="form-control"
                                id="fieldId"
                                ng-options="item.value as item.name for item in vfields[key].templateOptions.options"
                                ng-model="vmodel.vfields[key].key">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve that my post object looked like (except standards fields):

```
    object = {
          title = text,
          description = text,
          vfields[key].key = some text or option value (for each custom fields)
}
```

this is my [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/9DxGQcA5qVbETb1jwjlL) with my error, I appreciate if anybody could help me to find my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of accessing members with dot notation ' . ', use accessing them with bracket notation ' [ ] '.

The dot notation only works with property names which are valid identifier names [spec], so basically any name, would also be a valid variable name

Bracket notation expects an expression which evaluates to a string, so you can use any character sequence as property name.

Your ng-model should look like: `ng-model="vmodel[vfields[key].key]"`
Also you have a deal with simple array inside, there is no necessary to use `(key, value)`, just simple `ng-repeat='your name' in vfields`

This is your [fixed plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XNuA65jXglJi5g3k8vCd?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

`ng-model="vmodel.vfields[key].key"` is wrong change it to `ng-model="vfields[key].key"`

In fact i removed `vmodel` because you should not use angular copy

Use angular.copy when assigning value of object or array to another variable and that object value should not be changed.

Without deep copy or using angular.copy, changing value of property or adding any new property update all object referencing that same object

So you should use

```
 $scope.vmodel = params.model;
   $scope.vmodel.vfields = {};
```